# How can I unit test this inputStream has been closed?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a `Runnable` along the lines of:

```
    public void run() {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            //more stuff here
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            //simplified for reading
        }
        finally {
            if(inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {}
            }
        }
    }
```

How do I test `inputStream.close()` was invoked? I am currently using Mockito and JUnit. I know injecting the `inputStream` in is an idea, but I don't want the resources to be used until `run?()` is called, hence it being a local variable. So how can I redesign my code in a way that allows me to test whether close was called?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As there is no reason to expose the InputStream outside of the scope of this method you have a testing problem.

But I assume you don't directly care about the `InputStream` being closed. You want to test that because  you've been told it's good practice (and it is). But I think what you actually care about is the negative impact of the stream being left open. What is the effect?

Try modifying this method so it does not close the stream, then execute it many times over. Do you get a memory leak, or run out of file handles or some other tomfoolery? If so, you have a reasonable test.

Alternatively, just go ahead and expose a decorated InputStream that can tell you if it has been closed or not. Make it package protected. That's the "impure", but pragmatic approach.

Comment: +1, he got the point, it's important to test the impact of a failure not the internal behaiviour of a class.

Answer (score 18):

If I understood the task correctly it could be like this

```
static boolean isClosed;

public void run() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream(file) {
            @Override
            public void close() throws IOException {
                isClosed = true;
                super.close();
            }
        };
        // more stuff here
```

Comment: BTW, funny thing about FileInputStream is that it already has a field "closed" .

Answer (score 8):

To check if the close() method is called, you can use Mockito.spy() to create a proxy object that can memorize calls. Spy delegates all the calls to the underlying InputStream, just memorizes what happened:

```
InputStream inputStreamSpy = Mockito.spy(inputStream);
// a code that is expected to close your stream goes here ...
Mockito.verify(inputStreamSpy).close();
```

This won't solve your problems with injecting instance of InputStream, actually. It seems like you need some kind of factory, that can open a stream for you, and you can mock that factory in unit tests. Let's call this factory a FileSystem:

```
public class FileSystem {
    public FileInputStream newFileInputStream(File file) {
        return new FileInputStream(file);
    }
}
```

Now, you can inject an instance of the FileSystem, and it won't use resources before run method is executed:

```
public void run() {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = fileSystem.newFileInputStream(file);
        //more stuff here
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //simplified for reading
    }
    finally {
        if(inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}

@Test
public void runShouldCloseInputStream() {
    InputStream inputStream = ...
    InputStream inputStreamSpy = Mockito.spy(inputStream);
    FileSystem fileSystemMock = Mockito.mock(FileSystem.class);
    when(mockFileSystem.newFileInputStream(Mockito.any(File.class)))
        .thenReturn(inputStreamSpy);

    MyRunnable instance = new MyRunnable(mockFileSystem);
    instance.run();

    verify(inputStreamSpy).close();
}
```

Spy can do more then just listening, you can teach it to alter behavior using Mockito.when(), just as you would do with a regular mock.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin implementation for testing a URL stream is closed

```
//close the connection
streamURL.close()

//stream should not be available if it is closed
try { streamURL.available() }

//java.net.URL provides simple "closed" message on IO URL
catch (ex: IOException) { Assert.assertEquals("closed", ex.message) }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write in the test something like:

```
try {
    run();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Assert.fail();
}
```

When your method will close strem and exception will occur, then test will fail.

Comment: 1. That test won't fail if the `close` invocation is removed. 2. A thrown `IOException` would fail the test anyway.

Comment: Synesso, thank for your comment
1. We talk about case with close();
2. Can you explain please?

Comment: 1. yes, but the test is no good if it doesn't *fail* when the production code is broken. You get a 'false positive'. 2. If you don't catch the `IOException`, but instead let it be thrown, it adequately fails the test - no need for `try`, `catch` and `assert`

Comment: Does you mean that IOException will be able thrown elsewhere than when stream is closed?

Comment: That's not what I mean. If `run()` throws an `IOException` the test will fail even without the try/catch block. So the try/catch is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
    try
    {
         inputStream.readLine();        
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Assert.assertEquals(e.getLocalizedMessage(), "Stream closed");
    }
```